# Applying different LabelStyle conditionally fails

Tags: swiftui

I want my users to be able to define whether they want `.iconOnly` or `.titleAndIcon` behaviour for their label.

Unexpectedly to me though I am not able to apply on or the other style conditionally at the top of my view hierarchy:

[image]

Any suggestions on what needs to be done here?

Comment: Make a wrapper with explicit `if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible approach. Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

```
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func labelStyle(includingText: Bool) -> some View {
        if includingText {
            self.labelStyle(.titleAndIcon)
        } else {
            self.labelStyle(.iconOnly)
        }
    }
}
```

and usage like

```
TabView {
 // .. your code
}
.labelStyle(includingText: labelStyleShowText)
```