How to toggle DatePicker visibility with consistent alignment and spacing
I got a Button and DatePicker in a HStack. The button toggles the visibility of the picker. When the DatePicker is visible, the button label is set to .iconOnly. When the DatePicker is hidden, the Button label title and icon are visible. The issue is, the button icon and title jump around.
I want the Button label title to appear in the same place as the DatePicker label.
In my code here I have added a GeometryReader and a .border to try debug the position, but I cannot really make sense of what's going on.
HStack {
    Button {
        withAnimation {
            hasStartDate.toggle()
            if !hasStartDate {
                startDate = nil // Reset the date
            }
        }
    } label: {
        if hasStartDate {
            // Icon-only button for "remove start date"
            Label {
                Text("Remove Start Date")
            } icon: {
                Image(systemName: "minus.circle.fill")
                    .renderingMode(.original)
                    .foregroundColor(.red) // Tint for remove action
                    .imageScale(.medium)
            }
            .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
        } else {
            // Icon and text for "add start date"
            Label {
                Text("Add Start Date")
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
            } icon: {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                    .renderingMode(.original)
                    .foregroundColor(.green) // Tint for add action
                    .imageScale(.medium)
            }
        }
    }
    .buttonStyle(.plain)
    // Debug control  position
    .background(
        GeometryReader { geo in
            Color.clear
                .onAppear {
                    print("Button frame: \(geo.frame(in: .local))")
                }
                .onChange(of: hasStartDate) {
                    print("Button frame: \(geo.frame(in: .local))")
                }
        }
    )
    .border(.red, width: 1)
    // End debug control position

    if hasStartDate {
        DatePicker(
            "Start Date",
            selection: Binding(
                get: { startDate ?? Date() },
                set: { startDate = $0 }
            ),
            displayedComponents: .date
        )
        .datePickerStyle(.compact)
        // Debug control position
        .background(
            GeometryReader { geo in
                Color.clear
                    .onAppear {
                        print("DatePicker frame: \(geo.frame(in: .local))")
                    }
                    .onChange(of: hasStartDate) {
                        print("DatePicker frame: \(geo.frame(in: .local))")
                    }
            }
        )
        .border(.green, width: 1)
        // End debug control position
    }
}
// Debug control position
.background(
    GeometryReader { geo in
        Color.clear
            .onChange(of: hasStartDate) {
                let buttonFrame = geo.frame(in: .local)
                let datePickerFrame = geo.frame(in: .local)
                let spacing = datePickerFrame.minX - buttonFrame.maxX
                print("HStack total frame: \(geo.frame(in: .local))")
                print("Calculated spacing: \(spacing)")
            }
    }
)
.border(.blue, width: 1)
// End debug control position

Screen Recording GIF

EDIT: adding .padding(.leading) to the DatePicker aligns its label with the label of the Button so that "Add Start Date" and "Start Date" appear in the same place when toggled, but the icon-only state of the button still shifts to the left.

You could consider using a cusom date picker, see How to increase tappable area of DatePicker in SwiftUI for an example.

Here's what I've come up with. It's similar to what I had originally done but I wanted to avoid the hacky extension on the View. I don't really get why we can't use a ternary operator in .labelStyle so if you have any ideas how to make it look better be my guest.
This answer for the extension: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72489274/1573326
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State private var hasStartDate = false
    @State private var startDate: Date? = nil
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    hasStartDate.toggle()
                    if !hasStartDate {
                        startDate = nil
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                Label {
                    Text(hasStartDate ? "Remove Start Date" : "Add Start Date")
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                } icon: {
                    Image(systemName: hasStartDate ? "minus.circle.fill" : "plus.circle.fill")
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                        .foregroundColor(hasStartDate ? .red : .green) // Tint for remove action
                        .imageScale(.small)
                }
                .labelStyle(includingText: hasStartDate ? false  : true)
            }
            
            if hasStartDate {
                DatePicker(
                    "Start Date",
                    selection: Binding(
                        get: { startDate ?? Date() },
                        set: { startDate = $0 }
                    ),
                    displayedComponents: .date
                )
                .datePickerStyle(.compact)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func labelStyle(includingText: Bool) -> some View {
        if includingText {
            self.labelStyle(.titleAndIcon)
        } else {
            self.labelStyle(.iconOnly)
        }
    }
}


The parameter of the labelStyle modifier is LabelStyle, which is a protocol. Each type that conforms to it is a different type, and this makes it unusable for the ternary operator.
I have different approach:
Wrap the complete conditional view inside the button's label to work around the problem with labelStyle.
On our Text labels, we need to add the .allowsHitTesting(false) modifier to avoid triggering the Button's action here.
Other changes I made:

I give the new component a title to make it reusable.

The hasdate boolean can be computed, as it depends on existence of a date.


struct DateView: View {
    let title: String
    var hasDate: Bool {
        scheduleDate != nil ? true : false
    }
    
    @Binding private var scheduleDate: Date?
    
    init(title: String, scheduleDate:  Binding<Date?>) {
        self.title = title
        self._scheduleDate = scheduleDate
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            withAnimation {
                if scheduleDate == nil {
                    scheduleDate = Date()
                } else {
                    scheduleDate = nil
                }
            }
        } label: {
            Label {
                Group {
                    if hasDate {
                        HStack {
                            Text("\(title)")
                                .allowsHitTesting(false)
                            Spacer()
                            DatePicker(
                                "",
                                selection: Binding(
                                    get: { scheduleDate ?? Date() },
                                    set: { scheduleDate = $0 }
                                ),
                                displayedComponents: .date
                            )
                            .datePickerStyle(.compact)
                            .fixedSize()
                        }
                    } else {
                        Text("Add \(title)")
                            .padding(.vertical, 4) // Static fix for different height, not ideal for Dynamic Type support.
                                .allowsHitTesting(false)
                    }
                }
                .frame(alignment: .leading)
            } icon: {
                Image(systemName: hasDate ? "minus.circle.fill" : "plus.circle.fill")
                    .foregroundStyle(hasDate ? .red : .green)
            }
        }
        .buttonStyle(.plain)
    }
}

You can use it like this:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var startDate: Date? = nil
    @State private var someDate: Date? = Date()
    @State private var endDate: Date? = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            Text("Schedule")
                .font(.subheadline)
                .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
            
            DateView(title: "Start Date", scheduleDate: $startDate)
            DateView(title: "Some Date", scheduleDate: $someDate)
            DateView(title: "End Date", scheduleDate: $endDate)
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: 300, alignment: .leading)
    }
}


I like the idea of making it a reusable component. The problem in that example is wrapping the datepicker in the button, tapping the datepicker triggers the button action.

I added the .allowsHitTesting(false) modifier on the Textlabels to avoid triggering the Button's action here.
